# Get details from database such as name, company and etc, after clicking a selection from a list of items

Tags: php, sql, database, show, edit

Upon clicking to this page, I am able to edit most of the details in here, but all of the companies were listed to allow the editing of data.

WHAT IS NEEDED:
Page A: "Clicked on Company A's edit details"
Page B "Show only the edit entries for Company A"

WHAT IS ACTUALLY SHOWN IN THE CODES BELOW:
Page A: "Clicked on Company A's edit details"
Page B: "Shows all the edit entries for all the companies in the database"

I believe that I should not be using a while loop but since I'm getting here from another page, I would probably need to use a if/else statement to check for it.

In the list to be clicked:

```
                <!-- popup -->
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
                    <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Choose Action</li>
                    <li><a href="editCompany.php?id=<?php echo $row[$company_id]; ?>">Edit Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">View Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

AND in the edit page:

```
<?php
            if ($totalCompanies > 0) {
                ?>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    //$id = $row['id'];
                    $company_id = $row['company_id'];
                    $company_name = $row['company_name'];
                    $business_regno = $row['business_regno'];
                    $address = $row['address'];
                    $contact_num = $row['contact_num'];
                    $contact_name = $row['contact_name'];

                ?>
                <form id="editCompany" action = "doCreateCompany.php" method = "post">
                    <label id="company_name">Company Name: </label> 
                    <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" value="<?php echo $company_name ?>">

                    <label id="business_regno">Business Registration Number: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="business_regno" id="business_regno" value="<?php echo $business_regno ?>">

                    <label id="address">Address: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo $address ?>">

                    <label id="contact_num">Contact Number: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact_num" id="contact_num" value="<?php echo $contact_num ?>">

                    <label id="contact_name">Contact Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" value="<?php echo $contact_name ?>">

                    <input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" value="Save Company Details"/>
                </form>
                <?php
            } // end for loop
            ?>    
            <?php
                    } //end if
            mysqli_close($link);
            ?>
        </div>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be, if you add ?id= to your editlink.
This could look like this:

```
echo('<a href="path/to/file.php?id='.$row['company_id'].'">Edit details</a>');
```

You can then use $_GET['id'] and do a simple select statement with this id which will return only the company you need. But pay attention with the select because the id can be manipulated very easy.